# Getting NotSerializableException - When using Spark Streaming with Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using SparkStreaming for reading data from a topic. I am facing an exception in it.

> java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value:
>   ConsumerRecord(topic = rawEventTopic, partition = 0, offset = 14098,
>   CreateTime = 1556113016951, serialized key size = -1, serialized value
>   size = 2916, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly =
>   false), key = null, value =
>   {"id":null,"message":null,"eventDate":"","group":null,"category":"AD","userName":null,"inboundDataSource":"AD","source":"192.168.1.14","destination":"192.168.1.15","bytesSent":"200KB","rawData":"{username:
>   vinit}","account_name":null,"security_id":null,"account_domain":null,"logon_id":null,"process_id":null,"process_information":null,"process_name":null,"target_server_name":null,"source_network_address":null,"logon_process":null,"authentication_Package":null,"network_address":null,"failure_reason":null,"workstation_name":null,"target_server":null,"network_information":null,"object_type":null,"object_name":null,"source_port":null,"logon_type":null,"group_name":null,"source_dra":null,"destination_dra":null,"group_admin":null,"sam_account_name":null,"new_logon":null,"destination_address":null,"destination_port":null,"source_address":null,"logon_account":null,"sub_status":null,"eventdate":null,"time_taken":null,"s_computername":null,"cs_method":null,"cs_uri_stem":null,"cs_uri_query":null,"c_ip":null,"s_ip":null,"s_supplier_name":null,"s_sitename":null,"cs_username":null,"cs_auth_group":null,"cs_categories":null,"s_action":null,"cs_host":null,"cs_uri":null,"cs_uri_scheme":null,"cs_uri_port":null,"cs_uri_path":null,"cs_uri_extension":null,"cs_referer":null,"cs_user_agent":null,"cs_bytes":null,"sc_status":null,"sc_bytes":null,"sc_filter_result":null,"sc_filter_category":null,"x_virus_id":null,"x_exception_id":null,"rs_content_type":null,"s_supplier_ip":null,"cs_cookie":null,"s_port":null,"cs_version":null,"creationTime":null,"operation":null,"workload":null,"clientIP":null,"userId":null,"eventSource":null,"itemType":null,"userAgent":null,"eventData":null,"sourceFileName":null,"siteUrl":null,"targetUserOrGroupType":null,"targetUserOrGroupName":null,"sourceFileExtension":null,"sourceRelativeUrl":null,"resultStatus":null,"client":null,"loginStatus":null,"userDomain":null,"clientIPAddress":null,"clientProcessName":null,"clientVersion":null,"externalAccess":null,"logonType":null,"mailboxOwnerUPN":null,"organizationName":null,"originatingServer":null,"subject":null,"sendAsUserSmtp":null,"deviceexternalid":null,"deviceeventcategory":null,"devicecustomstring1":null,"customnumber2":null,"customnumber1":null,"emailsender":null,"sourceusername":null,"sourceaddress":null,"emailrecipient":null,"destinationaddress":null,"destinationport":null,"requestclientapplication":null,"oldfilepath":null,"filepath":null,"additionaldetails11":null,"applicationprotocol":null,"emailrecipienttype":null,"emailsubject":null,"transactionstring1":null,"deviceaction":null,"devicecustomdate2":null,"devicecustomdate1":null,"sourcehostname":null,"additionaldetails10":null,"filename":null,"bytesout":null,"additionaldetails13":null,"additionaldetails14":null,"accountname":null,"destinationhostname":null,"dataSourceId":2,"date":"","violated":false,"oobjectId":null,"eventCategoryName":"AD","sourceDataType":"AD"}))
>     - element of array (index: 0)
>     - array (class [Lorg.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;, size 1)     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:393)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_151]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_151]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
>
> 2019-04-24 19:07:00.025 ERROR 21144 --- [result-getter-1]
>   o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Task 1.0 in stage 48.0 (TID
>   97) had a not serializable result:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord

Code for reading topic data is below -

```
 @Service
public class RawEventSparkConsumer {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RawEventSparkConsumer.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataModelServiceImpl dataModelServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private JavaStreamingContext streamingContext;

    @Autowired
    private JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages;

    @Autowired
    private EnrichEventKafkaProducer enrichEventKafkaProd;

    @PostConstruct
    private void sparkRawEventConsumer() {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> {

            messages.foreachRDD((rdd) -> {

                List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rddList = rdd.collect();
                Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rddIterator = rddList.iterator();
                while (rddIterator.hasNext()) {
                    ConsumerRecord<String, String> rddRecord = rddIterator.next();

                    if (rddRecord.topic().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("rawEventTopic")) {
                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        BaseDataModel csvDataModel = mapper.readValue(rddRecord.value(), BaseDataModel.class);
                        EnrichEventDataModel enrichEventDataModel = (EnrichEventDataModel) csvDataModel;
                        enrichEventKafkaProd.sendEnrichEvent(enrichEventDataModel);

                    } else if (rddRecord.topic().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("enrichEventTopic")) {
                        System.out.println("************getting enrichEventTopic data ************************");
                    }

                }

            });

            streamingContext.start();

            try {
                streamingContext.awaitTermination();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
```

This is the configuration code.

```
@Bean
public JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> getKafkaParam(JavaStreamingContext streamingContext) {
            Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashedMap();
            kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
            kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
            kafkaParams.put("group.id", "group1");
            kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
            kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
            Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(rawEventTopic,enrichEventTopic);

            return KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    streamingContext,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
            );


        }
```

Pleasse help. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Can you please list our consumer configuration that you are using for your spark consumer

Comment: @Gokul Potluri Done. Please check the post

Comment: Basically, `rdd.collect()` should not be used... `ConsumerRecord` is not serializable. If you really need access to invididual `ConsmerRecord` objects, then you shouldn't be using Spark.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have to do some Manipulation on objects and then have to send them on another topic. Can you please help how i can achieve it?

Comment: Kafka Streams can do that very easily. Are you required to use Spark for that? If you are, then you're looking for `messages.map` to apply a function over each RDD. You really do not need a list or iterator

Comment: i have to run the things on cluster envirnoment. So i choose Spark. should i go with Spark?

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you give me some example link for reading data from kafka topic using kafkaStream.

Comment: You can still run multiple Kafka Streams applications in a clustered environment. https://spring.io/blog/2018/04/19/kafka-streams-and-spring-cloud-stream

Comment: Got a solution of my issue here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295838/org-apache-spark-sparkexception-task-not-serializable/29353465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution of my issue in below link -

[org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295838/org-apache-spark-sparkexception-task-not-serializable/29353465)

declare the inner class as a static variable :

```
static Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String> mapFunc=new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
        return tuple2._2();
    }
}
```